# std::string : Illegal use of this type as an expression

Tags: c++

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
enum MaybeType{
  Nothing,
  Just
};

template<typename T>
class Maybe{
  virtual MaybeType getType() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Just : public Maybe<T>{
  T value;
  virtual MaybeType getType() const{
    return MaybeType::Just;
  }
public:
  Just(T v) : value(v){}
};

template<typename T>
class Nothing : public Maybe<T>{
  virtual MaybeType getType() const{
    return MaybeType::Nothing;
  }
};

int main(){
  using namespace std;
  string s = "Hello";
  auto m = Just<string>(s); // error
}
```

I get the following error 'std::string' `error C2275: 'std::string' : illegal use of this type as an expression`

Why do I get this error and what does it mean in this context?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I marked the error in my code.

Comment: Look at the *first* error: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a986213dda77f390 You probably meant to use `enum class`.

Comment: First you have a duplication of `Just` in the code, the class name clashes with the `enum`. Make it a strong enum, i.e. an `enum class`. Second, there is a `;` missing in `return MaybeType::Nothing`. If you put it, the code compiles.

Comment: This problem could be avoided with a C++11 scoped enum :-)

Comment: This looks like an example from a Haskell book :)

Comment: @juanchopanza exactly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code provides two meanings for `Nothing` and `Just`:

- A value in an enumeration, and
- A template type

The compiler appears to prefer the former; you want the later.

In order to fix this, you could do one of three things:

- Rename your `enum` values,
- Rename your template classes, or
- Make sure that the two colliding names belong to different namespaces.

[Demo on ideone with the renamed `enum` constants.](http://ideone.com/2gg0bg)

[Demo on ideone with a separate namespace for the `enum`.](http://ideone.com/y3wIPX)

Comment: ... or make the enum a `enum class` so that the enumerators are already scoped...